# How to loop through 8 group boxes, display one group box at a time

Tags: vb.net, loops, controls

i was trying to use for each loop to select all group boxes and think of ways to make only one visible at a time.

```
For Each page As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf page Is GroupBox Then
        CType(page, GroupBox).Visible = False
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Whats the criteria for which one to show? Also please read [Ask] and take the [Tour] - titles are important for attracting the right attention

Comment: sorry, I will try to make next question simpler. So, I have 8 different groupboxes. and they all need to be displayed in order (1 to 8). I had just used Enum function to add names for all of the groupboxes to get an index number for each . but i cant connect the two together. I have the 8 index numbers but how do i use that to display each groupbox in order

Comment: The loop will act almost instantaneously. No one will know what order they were displayed in, so you are missing some tidbit. Please read [Ask] and take the [Tour]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A loop cannot display one at a time over a period of time.  Execution of a loop will be immediate so the user will only see the last one you show.  If you want to display a single, specific `GroupBox` then you can call the method below and pass that `GroupBox`:

```
Private Sub ShowGroupBox(groupBoxToShow As GroupBox)
    Dim groupBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)()

    For Each gb In groupBoxes
        gb.Visible = gb Is groupBoxToShow
    Next
End Sub
```

In order to show each and every `GroupBox` for a period of time each, you should use a `Timer`.  Each time the `Timer` raises its `Tick` event, you can show the next `GroupBox`.

```
Private groupBoxIndex As Integer = 0

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(...) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ShowGroupBox(groupBoxIndex)
    groupBoxIndex += 1
End Sub

Private Sub ShowGroupBox(groupBoxIndexToShow As Integer)
    Dim groupBoxes = Me.Controls.OfType(Of GroupBox)().ToArray()

    If groupBoxIndexToShow = groupBoxes.Length Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    Else
        For i = 0 To groupBoxes.GetUpperBound(0)
            groupBoxes(i).Visible = (i = groupBoxIndexToShow)
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see the point of your first `ShowGroupBox` method... You're passing a `GroupBox` as a parameter only to iterate every `GroupBox` in the form, and show any of them who are the same `GroupBox` as the parameter? All that can be replaced by `<group box variable>.Visible = True`, which will also be a lot faster.

Comment: As for the timer's `Tick` event, the parameters are: `(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)`.

Comment: @VisualVincent, with regards to your first comment, you're wrong. That code does not simply show the specified `GroupBox` and so it cannot be replaced by the code you provided. My code not only shows that one `GroupBox` but also hides all the others, which yours does not.

Comment: @VisualVincent, as for the parameters for the `Tick` event handler, I wrote that code by hand and couldn't be bothered writing them out but if you use the IDE to generate the event handler then you don't need to write them or even remember what they are.

Comment: there is one problem the groupbox dont show in the order i want them to. they all appear with order i dont want

Comment: The code I provided will create a list with the `GroupBoxes` in order that matches the z-order on the form.  To change that order, open the Document Outline window and then either drag the GroupBoxes into the order you want or use the arrow buttons on the toolbar.

Comment: You're certainly right about the groupboxes. It was 4 AM in the morning here so I couldn't think clearly. :)